# macOS Monterey - How do I temporarily disable a profile?

Tags: macos, monterey

I need to temporarily disable a profile shown in the picture below, i.e. I don't want to remove it and then add it again.

[image]

Can I do that?

Comment: If this is a profile added to your machine through a MDM from the institution you work for, you may be restricted from removing it at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no built-in way to "pause" a profile. You can remove the profile now, and then later add the same profile back.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do something along this line. In my case, I disabled a custom DoH profile from Quad9 that I was using temporarily by following these steps:

1. Go to **System Preferences > Network**
2. Select the **Quad9...** service
3. Click the three dots button at the bottom and select **Make Service Inactive**
4. Click **Apply**

[image: Screenshot of the Network preferences]

Just follow the same steps (but make the service active) when you want it to be active again.

Comment: Wow, is this a new feature added in Sonoma?

Comment: I don't think so, because I'm on Monterey. I'm not sure whether the presence of the service on the Network page depends on the installed profile or not though.

Comment: I just realised that this only works for Network profiles, not `Privacy & Security > Profiles` on Sonoma (yet).